# jQuery get Inner <tr> of a <table> with a different classes using the .find() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am trying to use jQuery to return a all the rows that are checked within my data table. A row is checked if span class="checked" (1st and 3rd row) and unchecked span class="" (2nd row). Is there a shortcut way using the jQuery .find() method to return all the rows. As opposed to iterating through all of the rows and comparing the span class attribute?

I know i could just use find() to get all the rows. But is there a way to define inner elements in the jQuery find method?

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="checker">
            <span class="checked">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkboxes">
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td> blah
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="checker">
            <span class="">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkboxes">
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td> blah
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="checker">
            <span class="checked">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkboxes">
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td> blah
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:has` selector or `has` method:

```
$('#myTable').find('tr:has(span.checked)');
```

Or:

```
$('#myTable tr').has('span.checked');
```

Comment: The .find() you provided worked like a charm! @undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should use "`closest`":

```
$('#myTable .checked').closest('tr')
```

You can do it generically by testing directly if the checkbox is checked

```
$('#myTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution using of `.closest()` and `.find()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkboxes").click(function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').find('td').toggleClass('blue');
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/4/)